# Java nested inner class access outer class variables

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Is it possible for the nested inner classes ABar and BBar to access main class's variables? For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public ABar abar = new ABar();
    public BBar bbar = new BBar();
    public int someCounter = 0;

    public class ABar {
        public int i = 0;
        public void someMethod(){
            i++;
            someCounter++;
        }
    }

    public class BBar {
        public void anotherMethod(){
            bbar.someMethod();
            someCounter++;
        }
    }
}
// then called using: //
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
myFoo.bbar.anotherMethod();
```

**Edit**

Seems the code I typed would have worked if i'd have tried it first; was trying to get help without being too specific. The code I'm actually having trouble with

Fails because of the error 'cannot make static reference to the non-static field stage'

```
public class Engine {
    public Stage stage = new Stage();
        // ...
    public class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
        // ...
        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            stage.alpha++;
        }
    }

    public class Stage extends MovieClip {
        public float alpha = 0f;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: I haven't tried it exactly as typed out, because my project is android based - same logic, doesn't work (no enclosing instance of Foo) `Foo.this.i++;`

Comment: Really? It bothered you testing this? This is not a constructive question.

Comment: seems harder to post here than to test it

Comment: Is your BBar missing "extends ABar"?

Comment: I've updated my original question to be more specific about the context and requirements, should probably do this in future rather than writing new code out of context and making it a generalized question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your code, yes, it is possible.

> Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members
>   of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private. Static
>   nested classes do not have access to other members of the enclosing
>   class.

See: [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: you should include the link to the oracle site if you are going to use direct quotes. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 0):

If your inner class extends the outer class, then it will have access to the outer class public and protected members. I just tired it and it worked. The construct is a bit odd, because it implies a sort of infinite loop in the class definition, but it seems to do the job.