# How am I accessing my main class from an anonymous class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, anonymous-inner-class

I thought I had a good grasp of what I was doing but whenever I feel like I have a good handle on something, I'm proven wrong :)

The code in question is this

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.m_button);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    }
```

My confusion is in the `new Intent()` and `startActivity` method.

I was under the assumption that as long as we're working inside an anonymous class `View.OnClickListener` that I'd have to do something like 
`MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);`

When I'm not inside the anonymous class, I can simply do
`new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);`

Can someone explain why I am able to call the `startActivity();` method but can't just use `this` in the intent parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of the anonymous inner class `this` is the anonymous class itself. To access the outer class `this` from the anonymous one you need to do `OuterClassName.this`.

However an inner class is allowed to access variables and methods from the outer class. Whether the inner class is anonymous or not makes no difference what-so-ever.

See:

[I thought inner classes could access the outer class variables/methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251922/i-thought-inner-classes-could-access-the-outer-class-variables-methods)

[Java nested inner class access outer class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042573/java-nested-inner-class-access-outer-class-variables)

This is one of the most important differences between static and non-static inner classes.

You only need the class name if (for example) you have a method with the same name in both classes so it call tell which one you mean. That's what is happening with `this`, both the inner and outer class have a `this` - so it defaults to the inner one unless you say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

From your inner class you can  use new `Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class)`

Because it's a `this` of your outer activity, not the inner class' `this`